# SwiftUI - how to properly reload a @ObservableObject object

Tags: swiftui, observers

I have commenced rewriting my app [RsyncOSX][1] to SwiftUI (a lot to learn). Configurations and schedules are read from permanent store and that is fine. The following code does the work:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Readdatafromstore {
    var profile: String?
    var configurationData: ConfigurationsSwiftUI
    var validhiddenIDs: Set<Int>
    var scheduleData: SchedulesSwiftUI

    init(profile: String?) {
        self.profile = profile
        self.configurationData = ConfigurationsSwiftUI(profile: self.profile)
        self.validhiddenIDs = self.configurationData.getvalidhiddenIDs() ?? Set()
        self.scheduleData = SchedulesSwiftUI(profile: self.profile, validhiddenIDs: self.validhiddenIDs)
    }
}
final class RsyncOSXdata: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rsyncdata: Readdatafromstore?
    @Published var configurations: [Configuration]?
    @Published var schedulesandlogs: [ConfigurationSchedule]?
    @Published var arguments: [ArgumentsOneConfiguration]?
    init(profile: String?) {
        self.rsyncdata = Readdatafromstore(profile: profile)
        self.configurations = self.rsyncdata?.configurationData.getconfigurations() ?? []
        self.schedulesandlogs = self.rsyncdata?.scheduleData.getschedules() ?? []
        self.arguments = self.rsyncdata?.configurationData.getarguments() ?? []
    }
}
```

the View is loaded with the following:

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(RsyncOSXdata(profile: "profilename"))
```

And the views reads the data by

```
@EnvironmentObject private var rsyncOSXData: RsyncOSXdata
```

The configurations are stored by profile and the question is: how to reload the @ObservableObject? The default profile is read and loaded at start.

Reloading the `@ObservableObject` object does not update the view...

**Solved**

The call of contentView is changed, the environmentObject is set when calling the sidebar functions ..

```
let contentView = ContentView()
...
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
```

And ContentView():

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedprofile: String?
    var profiles: [String]? {
        return Catalogsandfiles(profileorsshrootpath: .profileroot).getcatalogsasstringnames()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Profile: ", selection: $selectedprofile) {
                ForEach(0 ..< (profiles?.count ?? 0)) {
                    Text(self.profiles?[$0] ?? "").tag(self.profiles?[$0])
                }
            }
            SidebarNavigation().environmentObject(RsyncOSXdata(profile: selectedprofile))
            Text(selectedprofile ?? "Default")
        }
    }
}
```

Selecting a new profile now updates the view automatically as they is supposed to. I don´t now exactly now why the change fixed the issue, but it works..
[1]: https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX

Comment: It's been going on two years since I worked with SwiftUI & Combine, so please forgive me. What *exactly* is the issue? From what I remember, `@ObservableObject` is related to app state. Views "respond" to changes to it. (Correct where I'm wrong, appreciated in advance.) I'd think you **don't** "reload" app state. Now, maybe I'm "old school" - think `UIKit`, `Notifications`, or `UserDefaults`. But should you tag this as [Combine]?

Comment: Well, I am new to SwiftUI and learning :-) The `@ObservableObject` is how I make data read from store available for the Views which need the data... And any changes is published to the views... My problem is when the user select another profile, what is the correct way to reload the object.. In the Swift/Storyboard version I just create the class reading data again and the various views accessing data by protocol...

Comment: I am assuming when a new profile is selected, you would a show `ViewB`, that `ViewB` should have a property `@ObservableObject var profile: Profile`. So when ever any profile changes happens to that specific profile `ViewB` would react to it. Think of views that depend on some data. So either it can be internal or external, it might help to watch the apple developer videos on SwiftUI and passing data to SwiftUI

Comment: It would help if you posted your view code. That is where your problem is.

Comment: Just added code listing one view...

Comment: The profiles are catalogs containing data for that particular profile.. A new profile is read by a `Picker` and any change causes the `@ObserveableObject` to read new values - but the views does not pick up the changes...